# Linear transformation axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A transformation $f:$ R$^3$ to R$^3$ is defined by

$f(x, y ,z) = (x - 2y + 2z, 3x + y + 2z, 2x + y + z)$

Show that *f* is a linear transformation and the standard matrix of *f* (with respect to the standard basis of R$^3$)

Now a linear transformation is when

$T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v)$

And $cT(u) = T(cu)$

I still struggle to understand how to represent this in the context of the question. Do we use $(x, y, z)$ for $u$ or part of the definition?

For the matrix, I assume it's the coefficients in column form augmented with the identity matrix for R$^3$ then Gaussian-elimination can be used to calculate the new matrix. Correct?

Comment: Your description of linear transformation should say “For every **vector** $u$, every **vector** $v$, and every **scalar** $c$, $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ and $T(cu) = cT(U)$. Here, the vectors are the $3$-tuples of real numbers, and the scalars are real numbers.

Comment: No, “the matrix” is not an augmented matrix and you don’t do any Gaussian elimination. Have you not discussed the matrix representation of a linear transformation?

Comment: The descriptions aside, I want to understand how the process works. As for the matrix I guess I was thinking about new basis | old basis to find the transition matrix. Is that not the matrix that is required?